# Localizable.strings not working inside a List

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, localization, localizable.strings

To demonstrate my SwiftUI localization problem I have prepared [a simple test project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkLocalized/NaviLinkLocalized):

[image: screenshot]

It displays a list of games in the [ContentView.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkLocalized/NaviLinkLocalized):

```
List($vm.currentGames, id: \.self) { $gameNumber in
    NavigationLink(
            destination: GameView(gameNumber: gameNumber)
        ) {
        Text("game-number #\(gameNumber)")
    }
}
```

which is coming from the [GamesViewModel.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkLocalized/NaviLinkLocalized):

```
class GamesViewModel: ObservableObject /*, WebSocketDelegate */ {
    @Published var currentGames: [Int] = [20, 30]
    @Published var displayedGame: Int = 0
```

And for localization in DE, EN, RU I have added Localizable.strings:

```
"app-title" = "Wähle ein Spiel!";
"update-games" = "Spiele erneuern";
"join-random-game" = "Zufallsspiel beitreten";
"game-number #%d" = "Spiel #%d";
```

While the top 3 entries work well (you can see them as app title and the 2 button labels in the screenshot above), the last entry does not work (shown by the red arrow in the screenshot),

I have unsuccessfully tried many things:

- Replaced `%d` by `%lld`
- Removed the `#` char on both sides
- Replaced `game-number` by just `game`
- Tried to use `Text(LocalizedStringKey("game-number #\(gameNumber)"))`
- Tried to use `Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("game-number #%d", comment: ""), gameNumber))` - always shows the EN string "Game #..."

Nothing has helped, what could be wrong here please?

**UPDATE:**

I have received nice suggestions at the [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/how-to-localize-text-inside-a-list/10750) forum.

Comment: Use verbatim or LocalizedStringKey? Or are you saying that the other ones with a placeholder (and so a variable) works too? See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text

Comment: And `Text(LocalizedStringKey("game-number #\(gameModel.gid)"))` it doesn't fork either?

Comment: @Larme please take a look at my updated question! I have added a simple test project to it, to demo my problem. Unfortunately `Text(LocalizedStringKey("game-number #\(gameNumber)"))` does not help there either.

Comment: I'm not a SwiftUI user, so... But `Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("game-number #%d", comment: ""), gameNumber))` seems to work... I don't know why though...

Comment: Not really localized, unfortunately - your suggestion `Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("game-number #%d", comment: ""), gameNumber))` only displays the English string "Game" for me. Regardless of the language I select in the Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a bug for number formats, at least below works for strings.

```
List($vm.currentGames, id: \.self) { $gameNumber in
    NavigationLink(
        destination: GameView(gameNumber: gameNumber)
    ) {
        Text("game-number #\(String(gameNumber))")  // << here !!
    }
}
```

with combination in `.strings`

```
"game-number #%@" = "Game #%@";
"game-number #%@" = "Spiel #%@";
"game-number #%@" = "Игра #%@";
```

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

[image: demo]